# AspCore And Anuglar 2 templateUri

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, razor

I created a asp core project with angular 2. I use webpack for bundling and to load modules.

The project has the following structure

```
app
     /projects
          /createProjectComponent.ts
```

now as a first step i made a razor view which is routed to **/projects/create** and and the decorator looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'create-project',
    templateUrl:'projects/create'
})
```

everything works fine.

But now I don't like to mix razor views in this. so I placed a `createProjectComponent.html` in the `wwwroot` folder and adjusted the path of the decorator to .

```
@Component({
    selector: 'create-project',
    templateUrl:'createProjectComponent.html'
})
```

but from now on I don't see the content anymore when I call the  component.

In the network tab ofthe browser I can see that it sucessfully got the file and there are no errors in the browser console. 
So what am I missing?

Comment: If you're just loading straight into a component in your razor view without entering the app appropriately none of the Angular 2 framework/engine stuff will be loaded up.

Comment: thats clear. and I load all the framework and engine stuff. and as described above. it works everything when the parts are in razor views and the template uri points matches the view route. the only problem occurs when the view is placed in a file in wwwroot  and the uri points to that file which is served via the static file middleware